# horizontal layout with dynamic width to fill parent

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I have horizontal layout with 3 Children, the first has fix size, the third has fix size and align to .end and the second in center have to fill all parent size.

```
+-----mainnode------------------------------------+
|  +-------horizontallayout---------------------+ |
|  | [fix(10)] [ width that fill     ][fix(10)] | |
| +---------------------------------------------+ |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

any ideas? I use ASStackLayoutSpec horizontal

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

```
fix1.style.flexBasis = ASDimensionMake(10)
stretch.style.flexGrow = 1
fix2.style.flexBasis = ASDimensionMake(10)
```

Comment: I think it would make more sense to use `style.preferredLayoutSize` for first and third elements